# Importing the public keys that signed your key

Tags: gnupg

I recently lost my .gnupg folder. Luckily I had a backup of my private keys, however I'd like to reimport the public keys which have signed my key. How do I easily import all those - preferably at once?

```
pub   2048R/52AE9CEE 2012-01-20 [expires: 2015-02-09]
uid                  Thom Wiggers <antispamsnip>
sig 3        52AE9CEE 2012-01-20  Thom Wiggers <antispamsnip>
sig          2EF8C903 2012-12-04  [User ID not found]
sig 1        7E8162D1 2012-12-01  [User ID not found]
sig 2        EC362321 2012-11-29  [User ID not found]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
gpg --list-sigs | grep 'ID not found' | perl -nwe '/([0-9A-F]{8})/ && print "$1\n"' | xargs gpg --recv-keys
```

This should do what you want. It finds each missing user ID, then extracts the key ID and builds a list of public keys to fetch from the keyserver.

Comment: I've accepted it, since there apparently isn't a better way to do this without stuff like perl and xargs.

Comment: If you are using long hashes, change `{8}` to `{16}`.

Comment: Since the 32 bit 8 character gpg short ID is subject to a [collision attack](https://evil32.com/) you should use 64 bit key ids like @EddBarrett suggests to prevent collision, here's how : `gpg --list-sigs --keyid-format long | grep 'ID not found' | perl -nwe '/([0-9A-F]{16})/ && print "$1\n"' | xargs echo gpg --recv-keys`

Comment: Also keep in mind that the string "ID not found" will only match with an English locale, so setting LANG=C might be needed:

Answer (score 0):

To import a public key in your keyring, you need to *have* that public key. Since you lost your `.gnupg` folder, you also lost the local copies of the public keys you want to reimport, so you have to retrieve them "elsewhere". Public keys of other people are usually found on their Web pages, attached to signed emails they sent you, or on [public key servers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28cryptographic%29)

If the public keys you are after are indeed on key servers, then use `gpg --recv-keys` to retrieve them and import them in your keyring. E.g.:

```
$ gpg --recv-keys 2EF8C903
gpg: requesting key 2EF8C903 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key 2EF8C903: public key "Luuk Scholten <antispamsnip>" imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   7  signed:   4  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 7u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   4  signed:   0  trust: 3-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 1f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2013-09-23
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

As you see, this command found exactly one matching key for the specified ID, and imported it in my keyring.

(There is no security issue in importing public keys from other people in your keyring. *Importing* does not mean *trusting*.)

Comment: I know I can do it like this, but is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You can put several key IDs after `gpg --recv-keys` so I would say it is a matter of some simple scripting. I mean, do you have hundreds of keys to reimport ? How often do you expect to destroy your own `.gnupg` folder and have to rebuild it ?

Comment: I thought that perhaps there was a simpler tool/command for this that I was missing